# Flutter Provider.of<> doesn't work in sub class

Tags: flutter

in my application this codes work fine when i use them inside `flutter` main classes as `StatefulWidget`, `StatelessWidget` or `State`

```
final User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
final ConnectivityStatus connection = Provider.of<ConnectivityService>(context).connectivityStatus;
```

for example:

```
class FragmentMainApplicationBodyState extends State<FragmentMainApplicationBody>{

final User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
final ConnectivityStatus connection = Provider.of<ConnectivityService>(context).connectivityStatus;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
     return Text('${user.userController.userInfo.name}');
  }

}
```

now i'm trying use them inside sub-class, for example:

```
abstract class BaseState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State {
  bool isOnline = true;
  ConnectivityStatus connection;
  User user ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initConnectivity();
  }

  Future _initConnectivity() async {
    connection = Provider.of<ConnectivityService>(context).connectivityStatus;
    isOnline = connection == ConnectivityStatus.Connected;
    user = Provider.of<User>(context);
  }
}
```

when i implementing them in the class, `Providers` doesn't work in this implementation

**i get `NULL` for both of theme**

```
class FragmentMainApplicationBodyState extends BaseState<FragmentMainApplicationBody>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
     return Text('${user.userController.userInfo.name}');
  }
}
```

`MultiProvider` structure:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<User>.value(value: User()),
ChangeNotifierProvider<ConnectivityService>.value(value: ConnectivityService()),
```

**User**:

```
class User extends ChangeNotifier{
  UserController userController;
}

class UserController {
  UserInfo userInfo;
  PageInfo pageInfo;

  UserController(
      {@required this.userInfo,
      @required this.pageInfo,
      });
}
```

**ConnectivityService** :

```
enum ConnectivityStatus { Connected, Disconnected }

class ConnectivityService extends ChangeNotifier {
  ConnectivityStatus connectivityStatus;

  ConnectivityService() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
      await _updateConnectionStatus().then((bool isConnected) {
        connectivityStatus = isConnected ? ConnectivityStatus.Connected : ConnectivityStatus.Disconnected;
      });
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  Future<bool> _updateConnectionStatus() async {
    bool isConnected;
    try {
      final List<InternetAddress> result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        isConnected = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      isConnected = false;
      return false;
    }
    return isConnected;
  }
}
```

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you help me please?

Comment: Shouldn’t you be extending State<T>? Not sure if that’s gonna fix the problem though

Comment: @haroldolivieri could you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58039923/1830228